# Batch file to find string in a req query

Tags: string, cmd, registry

This is what I have thus far:

```
set bit=reg query HKLM\HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\System\CentralProcessor\0 /v Identifier
%bit%
    Identifier    REG_SZ    x86 Family 6 Model 23 Stepping 10
```

I want to search the `%bit%` to display x86 as, if x86 exist then run `test.exe`.

I know about `%processor_architecture%` which I will probably use but I do need to know this format for other registry queries.

Comment: That most certainly is not what you have, because `cmd` doesn't allow for command substitution via `set`.

Comment: Cmd does have set command as stated in the technet library http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490998.aspx

Comment: I'm aware that `cmd` has a `set` command, I just didn't realize that you assigned a command to a variable only to run the command via that variable. Why don't you simply run the command directly and avoid the confusion?

Comment: The reason I have it going to a variable is so that the output from the command can go to that variable and I can search that variable for a specific string. Then I can compare that specific string to a different string so the batch program can decide what to do.

Comment: The output isn't going to that variable. That had me confused in the first place, because that would be command substitution, which `cmd` does not support (not in that context, that is). What happens is that the command **string** goes into the variable, and when you put `%bit%` at the beginning of a line, the variable is expanded to the command string, which is then executed by the interpreter. Try adding a line `echo %bit%`. If command output really went into the variable, that line would print that output. Which it doesn't.

Comment: You are so correct and I have learned something. I tried a couple of things and I don't think what I had in mind is possible but at least I was able to get an answer to my post even if it isn't how I expected it to be. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am making this to simplify it for future users but many thanks to mrt for helping me with it.

```
set bit=reg query HKLM\HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\System\CentralProcessor\0 /v Identifier
    %bit%|findstr "x86" >NUL
If %errorlevel% equ 0 (set type=x86)
IF %type% equ x86 (winver.exe)
```

Comment: You can simply run `reg query HKLM\HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\System\CentralProcessor\0 /v Identifier | find "x86" >nul` to the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understood your question properly but if all you want to know is if your `reg query` returns 'x86' then you could do it like this:

```
%bit%|findstr "x86" >NUL
If %errorlevel% equ 0 (echo x86)
```

Comment: Thats good but I need it to verify that x86 is whats there like If %bit2% equ X86 then. P.S. the reason it has to be in batch is because .net is not on every computer and neither is power shell. Although something in VB would work if it covered XP to 7

Comment: This is what I came up with                                      set bit=reg query HKLM\HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\System\CentralProcessor\0 /v Identifier
%bit%|findstr "x86" >NUL
If %errorlevel% equ 0 (set type=x86)
IF %type% equ x86 (winver.exe)  and it works I will save this for future projects that require this. Thank you mrt